# Ubuntu stuck on login page - can't login with keyboard

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I don't know why but my Ubuntu session got stuck at the login page suddenly and I can't get through any further. When starting the VM, I get the following screen :
[image: Not listed]

I've tried `CTRL+ALT+F1` and `CTRL+ALT+F7` but no luck... My keyboard and mouse aren't working.

I've also tried `CTRL+ALT+F3` and ran

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session
```

but still the same.

[[image: Sign in screen.]]

I'm wondering what's wrong and what I can do. If ever it is not possible to recover my session, is there a way to create another VM with the disk of this one... I'd hate to lose everything.

[image: linux distrib]

Comment: Check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: thx Ekure Edem, i tried the following : `sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade`
`sudo apt-get -y install fglrx` ; I can now login with a news "Debian" Gui. However, I'm wondering if I can try to go back to the previous ubuntu ?

Comment: another (stupid) question, since I'm new to Linux and this new Gui, if I understand well this a lighter Gui version ? also, any idea on how to find the terminal with this ? `CTRL+ALT+T` doesn't work, nor "Run+Terminal"